# PHP - Ping another PHP file on a remote server

Tags: php, centos

Before I ask the question I will explain the setup.

**server 1:** vps with CentOS
**server 2:** vps with CentOS

On server1 I have /var/www/html/test.php
This file must ping get.php on the other server, with some POST variables.

On server2 I have /home/somedir/get.php

So is it possible to ping a file, which is not a webfile?

Comment: php can be executed as a command line script, so yes, it's possible.

Comment: Define `ping`. Do you mean a HTTP POST request?

Comment: Just so it runs the file on server2

Comment: Yes. When you view test.php in http it runs get.php on the other server.

Comment: Make a php file on server1, in that file you use curl to open the url to the file on server2.. And if it's not remotely accessible, use telnet or ssh to log in via a php script.

Comment: No. Because the file on server2 is not in the web diretory

Comment: Use ssh2_exec() http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH into server2 via ssh2_exec(). Modified example from php.net:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('server2.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'php /home/somedir/get.php');
?>
```

Above file should be placed on server1.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php